# The property favorited does not exists at the object

Tags: typescript, react-native, api

I am calling the third-party API and the `data` does not have the `favorited` property, then I added the property `favorited` at the `interface StocksProps`:

#### Interface StocksProps

```
interface StocksProps {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ticker: string;
  minimumValue: number;
  profitability: number;
  favorited: boolean;
}
```

But at the time when I call the API I use the `setStocks` remembering that this API call is inside the `useEffect` hook.
The API data comes

```
"success":true,
"data":[
 {
   ...
 },
 {
   ...
 },
],
"error": null
```

#### API get

```
api.get('stocks').then((response) => {
  const stocksDataOrdered =
    response.data.data.sort((stockA: StocksProps, stockB: StocksProps) =>
      stockA.name.localeCompare(stockB.name));
  setStocks(stocksDataOrdered);
  setLoading(false);
});
```

And I'm trying to make the heart empty, full after I click on the heart, but when I give a console.log () in the action that has the id, it doesn't come with any properties called favorited.

```
const handleStockAsFavorite = useCallback((id: number) => {
   const stockToChangeTheFavoriteValue = stocks.find(element => element.id === id);
   console.log(stockToChangeTheFavoriteValue);
   setFavoriteStock(false)
}, [stocks]);
```

```
<FavoriteButton onPress={() => handleStockAsFavorite(stock.id)}>
    <FavoriteImage source={favoriteStock ? favoritedImg : unfavoriteImg} />
</FavoriteButton>
```

The log comes
`{"id": 3, "minimumValue": 400.2, "name": "Banco do Brasil Seguridade", "profitability": 27.05, "ticker": "BBSE3"}`

Answer (score 1):

When you create an interface in typescript, you're really just making a note that you intend to use it that way. The interface is actually completely removed from the compiled javascript, it's only used to make sure you don't accidentally access properties that you said don't exist. If you want to add a new property that the API doesn't give you, you'll need to explicitly set it on each object as it comes in.

Comment: Hi, I tried to make a map after the `sort()` function returning the `...stock` and the `favorited: false` but do I always check if the `favorited` is undefined?

Comment: @Vagner That's the right approach.  If you set `favorited: false` on every stock before saving it to the `stocks` state then you know that every element of `stocks` cannot have `undefined`.